# Xcode storyboard showing different design from simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm learning iOS and following a tutorial to create a basic app. Everything was going well until the button to change segues has now disappeared?

There's another button on the next screen linking back in the same position as history that has also disappeared.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening?

[image: Button not showing on simulator vs storyboard.]

Comment: I'd say it's simply off screen. Try running an iPhone 5 simulator and check if you see the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be, that your storyboard displays the 4-inch display, while your simulator runs a 3.5-inch display.
You can switch the storyboard and the simulator between both options.

[image]
[image]

In order to fit the layout on both displays you should add constraints.